# Multiple or Wildcard SSL?

Tags: zend-framework, ssl-certificate

Please can you advise whether we need a wildcard SSL or 2 separate SSL certificates?

My domain DNS A records are:
mydomain.com / 
*.mydomain.com

We have built an application with Zend Framework which will alter routes and create subdomains for 1000's of users like user.mydomain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need a wildcard certificate. A standard SSL certificate verifies a SINGLE dns hostname, like "www.domain.com". You'd need a separate certificate for EACH of your individual user hostnames, which will probably bankrupt you and make godaddy/verisign very happy.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Marc is wrong here. I have a zend application that secure multiple subdomains using a single wild card ssl certification. The only issue is that all the subdomains have to be under the same root domain. You can't mix different subdomains with different domains.

For example, user1.mydomain.com or user2.mydomain.com.

In apache, you should set a catch all for the ssl port and you're good to go!

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName admin.mydomain.com
  ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/public
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: @Marc B said you need a wildcard certificate. You said the same thing. How is Marc wrong?

Answer (score -2):

Wildcard SSL is relatively expensive, considering you only have 2 sub domain, it's better to use multi-san ssl which are used to secure 2 domain (or sub domain) only. The latter one is much cheaper.